# Asymptotic Distribution of Product of Asymptotically Normal Random Variables

Tags: distributions, asymptotics

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be sequences of random variables such that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu_X)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_X)$ and $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\mu_Y)\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_Y)$ as $n\to\infty$. The sequences are not independent, and $(X_n,Y_n)$ does not converge in distribution to a normal distribution (otherwise the multivariate delta theorem can be used to answer my question below).

Are there standard approximations of the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(X_nY_n-\mu_X\mu_Y)$? I guess that one cannot derive the exact asymptotic distribution (?).

Comment: It seems to me you can't even demonstrate the last expression even *has* an asymptotic distribution. Suppose, for instance, that $X_n=Y_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1/n).$ Then $n X_nY_n$ has a non-central chi-squared distribution with mean $1+\mu^2$ and variance $2(1+2\mu^2),$ so subtracting $\mu_X\mu_Y=\mu^2$ doesn't center it and multiplying by $\sqrt{n}$ does not standardize its variance, meaning you're in trouble on all counts.

Comment: But what about $\sqrt{n}(X_n^2-\mu^2)$? You seem to be talking about $nX_n^2-\mu^2$ or a standardized version of it, but not $\sqrt{n}(X_n^2-\mu^2)$.

Comment: Since $X_n,Y_n$ are not independent, we have that in general $E(X_nY_n) \neq E(X_n)E(Y_n)$ and so the variable $Y_nX_n - \mu_X\mu_Y$ is not and does not become zero-mean, hence $\sqrt{n}(X_nY_n-\mu_X\mu_Y)$ will diverge.

Comment: Is $E(X_nY_n-\mu_X\mu_Y)=0$ a necessary condition for $\sqrt{n}(X_nY_n-\mu_X\mu_Y)$ to have an asymptotic distribution?